# Why wouldn't this code run in Java? Eror : <identifier> expected

Tags: java, class, oop, inner-classes

To call function of an inner class, all I need is an object of the inner class. But if I have the created the object, Why Can't I call the method of inner class anywhere I want? What is the error trying to imply?

```
class Outer 
{
    int x;
    
    class Inner // creating an Inner class
    {
        public void display()
        {
            System.out.println("Hello from Inner class"+x);
        }
    }
    
    Inner i = new Inner();
    i.display(); // This is where the error comes. Why do I have to create a method to call
                 // methods of my inner class. Why Can't I call it anywhere I want?
}


public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: _When_ do you expect `i.display()` to run?!

Comment: move `Inner i = new Inner(); i.display(); ` to `main`

Comment: Seeing as you understand you need to create a method or a block, you already know how to fix your issue. what's the actual question then?

Comment: I know  how to fix it and I also know I cannot call or use that line of code unless I move it into a method. But I know it cause I have a brain while the compiler doesn't. So why is Compiler rejecting this code?

Comment: @nSack for the same reason the compiler will refuse public void doInt(int a) -> doInt("clearly not a primitive"). It checks whether or not your code is valid. If it isn't, it can't compile it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So why is the compiler rejecting this code?

Because the code is syntactically invalid as Java, and the Java compiler is **required** to reject code that is invalid.

The Java language specification says that the only things that can be immediately nested in a class are member declarations or initializer blocks.  Member declarations are:

- field declarations
- nested classes, interfaces, enums, etcetera
- methods
- constructors

Initializer blocks are either `static` initializer blocks or instance initializer blocks.

A typical statement (like the one you are trying to insert there) is neither a member declaration or a block.

---

The relevant section of the Java Language specification is [JLS 8.1.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6)

Comment: But then why does putting the same 2 lines of code inside the main() function does the job?

Comment: That is a different question.  But if you are asking why it is syntacticly valid, the answer is that the syntax rules for what is allowed in a method body are *different* to the rules for a class body.

Comment: And if you are asking why the rules are different ... well, basically it is because that is how the language was designed.  The rationale is moot.  If you want your Java to compile, you must follow the Java syntax rules.

Comment: Thank you. For some reason, I was directly relating my outer class with the main class and totally ignoring the fact that content written inside main class is actually inside main() method. I Know it was a silly doubt but thanks a ton for clearing it.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to run a piece of code directly in the class body. The body of the class must be used only for initializations and function creation. What `Java` does, is go through all the created members of the class and initialize them just as you have done with `Inner i = new Inner()`.

To run a piece of code, it **must** be inside a function, and this function must be called! A very good example is the `main()` function. Anything you write in it will be executed since this function will be called right after a program is run.

But if an error is thrown in the middle of the function, you should also know that the execution will be interrupted and the commands will not be executed till the end.

Comment: So is this why using that same code[which gave me error in class Outer] inside the main() function will no longer give me an error? Because main() function is automatically called while my Outer function is not?

Comment: @nSack exactly. The compiler will not throw an error because the calling of functions inside another function is allowed. And yes `main()` will be called right after the program is run, all the other class functions will not! Except when they are explicitly called somewhere in the chain of executions, starting always from `main()`.